# How can I test equality of a pandas series in a dict?

Tags: pandas, dictionary, series

I've wrapped a pandas series into a dict: `dict = {'0': pd.Series(...)}`. During unit testing I'd like to assert equality of the series contained in the dict in comparison to an expected pandas series. However plain `assert dict == expected_dict` does not work due to `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`. For a plain series I usually use [pandas.testing.assert_series_equal](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_series_equal.html). How can I test a pandas series equality which is wrapped into a dict?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, in order to test whether two `pandas.Series` are equal you can use [`pandas.Series.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.equals.html). Also, you can refer to the Series wrapped in the dictionary by using its corresponding key (in this case `'0'`)

```
import pandas as pd

exp_series = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
d = {'0': pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'])}
pd.Series.equals(d['0'], exp_series)
# False

exp_series = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
d = {'0': pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])}
pd.Series.equals(d['0'], exp_series)
# True
```